# Cant send json to server

Tags: android, json, server

I'm trying to send a json file to remote server. If I try it, using this site:

https://www.hurl.it/ passing a json like this:
[image]

it works. But If I try it from my code, I have some trouble.

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs1 =  new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            JSONArray list1 = new JSONArray();
            list1.add("12345678");

            Map obj=new LinkedHashMap();
            obj.put("company_id","1");
            obj.put("phones", list1);
            obj.put("name","Alexy");
            obj.put("birthdate","12.03.2014");
            obj.put("email","nesalexy@mail.ru");

            nameValuePairs1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", obj.toString()));

            try {

                URL url = new URL("http://crm.pavlun.info/api/register");

                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url.toURI());

                httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(nameValuePairs1.toString(), "UTF-8"));

                httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "application/json");

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);   
                Log.e("r ",  response.toString());


            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

This is my json example: I need to create something like this: `"json":{"company_id":"1","phones":["555555"],"photo":"/files/clients_photos/tmp/484629825.JPG","name":"sdfsdfdsf","birthdate":"10.02.2014", "email":"sdf@sdf.ff"}`

**UPD:**

I have the following error:

```
{"status":"error","message":"Customer data is empty!"}
```

Maybe something is wrong in my json.

**UDP:**

working code

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs1 =  new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            JSONObject joB = new JSONObject();

            JSONArray list1 = new JSONArray();
            list1.add("258963147");

            Map obj=new LinkedHashMap();
            obj.put("company_id","1");
            obj.put("phones", list1);
            obj.put("name","Alexy");
            obj.put("birthdate","12.03.2014");
            obj.put("email","nesalexy@mail.ru");

            org.json.JSONObject jsonqwe;

            try {
                JSONParser operationLink = new JSONParser();
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> postP = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                postP.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", JSONValue.toJSONString(obj)));
                jsonqwe = operationLink.makeHttpRequest("http://crm.pavlun.info/api/register", "POST", postP);

                Log.e("sad", jsonqwe.toString());


            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: what error did you get? Did you run your code inside your UI thread?

Comment: @yaa110 i have error server `{"status":"error","message":"Customer data is empty!"}` maby i post wrong, or wrong my json

Comment: Can you print the json before sending it?

Comment: inspect what you are sending. `obj.toString()` is not json.

Comment: also, `nameValuePairs1.toString()`, not going to work.

Comment: @Joseph82 if i output `Log.e("name value pairs ", nameValuePairs1.toString());` its display  [json={"birthdate":"12.03.2014","company_id":"1","email":"nesalexy@mail.ru","name":"Alexy","phones":["12345678"]}]

Comment: @njzk2 what are you instead advise `nameValuePairs1.toString()`?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/entity/UrlEncodedFormEntity.html instead of `StringEntity`

Answer (score 1):

You're problem is that you're not building a JSON object, but using the map's `toString()` method, which won't give you a properly formatted JSON object.

Try JSONObject's [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject(java.util.Map)) that takes a map as parameter. And than call `toString()` on the JSONObject.

Answer (score 1):

This line will return garbage (as far server is concerned)

```
nameValuePairs1.toString()
```

because an `ArrayList` does implement `toString` like you are expecting.  You should be using `JSONArray`/`JSONObject` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try yo change

```
Map obj=new LinkedHashMap();
```

to

```
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
```

you need to send a JSON value

Comment: This is using map: https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples and if i change its still not work(

Comment: Change nameValuePairs1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", obj.toString())); to nameValuePairs1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", JSONValue.toJSONString(obj)));

Comment: see the Example 1-3 - Encode a JSON object - Using Map in the wiki

Comment: i change `nameValuePairs1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", obj.toString()))` to `nameValuePairs1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", JSONValue.toJSONString(obj)))` but i still have error `{"status":"error","message":"Customer data is empty!"} ` (

Answer (score 1):

A more suitable solution would be to build a JSONObject instead of the Map you're using. Something like this:

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs =  new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
JSONArray phoneNumbers = new JSONArray();
phoneNumbers.add("12345678");
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
obj.put("company_id","1");
obj.put("phones", phoneNumbers);
obj.put("name","Alexy");
obj.put("birthdate","12.03.2014");
obj.put("email","nesalexy@mail.ru");

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", obj.toString()));

try {

URL url = new URL("http://crm.pavlun.info/api/register");

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url.toURI());

httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(nameValuePairs.toString(), "UTF-8"));

httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "application/json");

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);   
Log.e("r ",  response.toString());


}catch(Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: i have `05-04 21:54:22.960: E/responseString:(10174): {"status":"error","message":"Customer data is empty!"}
` (

Answer (score 1):

In the hurl site example one name valu pair is sent. To send name value pais your content type should be form url encoded. So change:

```
          httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
          httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "application/json");
```

to

```
          httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Maybe this will help:

```
          httpPost.setHeader("ENCTYPE","multipart/form-data");
```

EDIT:

As others already stated do not use a Map but a JSONObject. Then change

```
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(nameValuePairs1.toString()));
```

to:

```
String nameValuPairsText = nameValuePairs.toString();                
nameValuPairsText = nameValuPairsText.substring(1, nameValuPairsText.length()-1);   
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(nameValuPairsText, "UTF-8"));
```